# Setting status callback URL using Python - Flask

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I am trying to use Python - Flask to test the StatusCallback in Twilio, however, I am not getting any results, not sure what I am missing. I am using ngrok as well.

This is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods =['POST', 'GET'])
def webhook():
    status=request.values.get(['CallSid', 'From', 'To', 'Direction'])
    logging.info('Status: {}'.format(status))
    return ('', 204)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I make a call, from the image I attached, you will notice I am not getting any results. Could you please advise what I may be missing? Thanks.

[image: attachment]

Comment: I am also using adding the url in StatusCallback=https://ngrok.io/webhook

Comment: Is there a subdomain missing on that ngrok URL? Do you see any requests being made through the ngrok tunnel? You can check this by opening the ngrok dashboard by visiting localhost:4040 when ngrok is running.

Comment: Hi @philnash, thanks, that helped. Is it possible to retrieve all the parameters using request.values.get? so e.g., something like request.values.get(['CallSid', 'Direction'])? When I add more parameters, it fails, but when there is only one parameter, it works.

Comment: I used call_info = request.form.to_dict(flat=False) and that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you create a tunnel with ngrok, a URL is set up that looks like `https://RANDOMSUBDOMAIN.ngrok.io`, make sure you are using the entire URL, including the subdomain.

When ngrok is running there is also a dashboard you can check to ensure that requests are being made to your ngrok URLs. You can reach this dashboard at `http://localhost:4040`. You can also use this to check the request parameters that are being sent.

Finally, you might have trouble with `request.values.get` and passing an array of keys. The [`get` method of `request.values`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get) only takes a single key, not an array.

As you pointed out in the comments, you can use `request.form.to_dict(flat=False)` to get a dictionary of the parameters instead. If you want to destructure that further into separate variables in a single line, you can use [`itemgetter` from the operator module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), like this:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

@app.route('/webhook', methods =['POST', 'GET'])
def webhook():
    parameters=request.form.to_dict(flat=False)
    CallSid, From, To, Direction = itemgetter('CallSid', 'From', 'To', 'Direction')(parameters)
    logging.info('CallSid: {}'.format(CallSid))
    return ('', 204)
```